# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in classipress

Tags: php

I got an Error While i submit the Ad if i can not check the mandatory field in form,

**The Error Is**

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/*******/public_html/wp-content/themes/classipress/includes/views-checkout.php
>   on line 1358

-

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/*******/public_html/wp-content/themes/classipress/includes/views-checkout.php
>   on line 954

Comment: Ask to help without providing code is unusefull

Answer (score 0):

Check the code once foreach() can only accept array or object.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

Provide code where you have this problem so I can help you better

**foreach()** can only accept the array or object